# TypeError: Cannot set property 'emailIsValid' of undefined with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

i'm trying to figure out why "this" is undefined, even though the assignment with Lodash worked (debugging shows that this refer to the function as expected):

creation:

```
validPerson = new Person({
        first: "Test",
        last: "User",
        email: "test@test.com"
    })
```

Person module:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

let pesron = (args) => {

  _.assignIn(this, args);

  this.emailIsValid = () => {
    return this.email && this.email.length > 3 && this.email.indexOf('@') > -1;
  };

};

export default person;
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'emailIsValid' of undefined
```

And again, the `_.assignIn` works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an arrow function and `this` is bound to nothing. **Arrow functions cannot be used as constructors.**

Read more about Arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Use a normal function instead:

```
let pesron = function(args) {

  _.assignIn(this, args); // this is now bound the current function 

  this.emailIsValid = () => {
    return this.email && this.email.length > 3 && this.email.indexOf('@') > -1;
  };

};
```

When calling `new` you need to have a constructor. e.g using ES6:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, last, email){
    this.first = name;
    this.last = last;
    this.email = email;
  }

  emailIsValid() {
    return this.email && this.email.length > 3 && this.email.indexOf('@') > -1;
  };

};

const p = new Person("Jonathan","Dion", "email@gmail.com")

console.log(p.first) // Jonathan
console.log(p.emailIsValid(p.email)) // true
```